# Batch delete dased on file name

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder that gets used for importing values from csv files into an excel spread sheet. This means that multiple times a day I need to delete and rename batches of files to work with the provided macro. I've automated the deleting and renaming, but the delete part of my batch file is more than a little clumsy, and is only coded to work with 20 files. It looks as follows:

```
del 1.csv
del 2.csv
etc
```

I'd like to loop this part of the batch file, but the only code I've found deletes based on file extension and not file name. What I'd like is to delete all single or double digit named csv files and to preserve any csv not in the same format. Any help or pointing to resources will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely understand but I think you're looking for the `for /l` command:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,[number for last file]) do del %%a.csv
```

e.g.

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,10) do del %%a.csv
```

will delete 1.csv to 10.csv

Hope this helped

Yours, Mona

Answer (score 1):

Try this - if it echoes the right filenames then remove the echo.  It should delete CSV files with 2 or 1 character names, that are numbers.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir ??.csv /b ^|findstr /r "^[0-9]*" ') do echo del "%%a"
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete one-digit files:

```
for /L %%a in (0,1,9) do del %%a.csv
```

To delete two-digit files:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set number=99
for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do (
   set /A number+=1
   del !number:~-2!.csv
)
```